# How to properly implement a tag layout in UICollectionView. I am getting crash

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, tags

I'm trying to implement a tag layout using UICollectionView in my app. I want to implement something like this:

[image: What I'm trying to implement]

My custom flow layout code is following:

```
// Custom Flow Layout to keep Items left aligned in collection view
class LeftAlignedCollectionViewFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
   override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        guard let attributes = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect) else {
            return nil
        }

        let collectionViewWidth = collectionView?.frame.width ?? 0
        var rows = [Row]()
        let spacing: CGFloat = 8
        var offsetY: CGFloat = 0
        var offsetX: CGFloat = 10

        rows.append(Row())

        for attribute in attributes {
            let neededWidth = CGFloat(attribute.frame.width) + spacing
            let neededMaxX = offsetX + neededWidth

            if neededMaxX <= collectionViewWidth {
                attribute.frame.origin.x = offsetX
                attribute.frame.origin.y = offsetY
                offsetX = neededMaxX
                rows.last?.add(attribute: attribute)
            } else {
                offsetY += (rows.last?.attributes.last?.frame.height ?? 0) + spacing
                attribute.frame.origin.x = spacing
                attribute.frame.origin.y = offsetY
                offsetX = attribute.frame.origin.x + neededWidth
                rows.append(Row())
                rows.last?.add(attribute: attribute)
            }
        }
        return rows.flatMap { $0.attributes }
    }
}

class Row {
    var attributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()
    init() {}
    func add(attribute: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) {
        attributes.append(attribute)
    }
}
```

I tried this custom layout code but I'm getting following crash:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Rounding frame ({{8.9884656743115785e+307, 8.9884656743115785e+307}, {210, 32}}) from preferred layout attributes resulted in a frame with one or more invalid members ({{inf, inf}, {210, 32}}).

Please point me out what wrong I'm doing here.

Comment: I've tried to run your code and it seems it's not complete to localise the problem (In my case it calculates sizes incorrectly without `itemSize` set, so probably there are more moments in your project which can cause this error). But, looking at this code, I would check `attribute.frame.width` values, whether they are valid or not.